# React and wrappers for plotly.js charting

Tags: javascript, plot, reactjs, plotly

I am having trouble with two different wrapper for Plotly.js:

[react-plotlyjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-plotlyjs) and [react-plotly](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-plotly)

If anybody can successfully get react-plotly or react-plotlyjs to work (with data updates) on react please let me know, I have been stuck for over a day...

I had no issue gets chartjs to work, but they don't have a polar scatter plot. From what I've seen online only plotly.js has a free polar scatter plot.

My issue with react-plotlyjs wrapper is that I cannot update the model data. If I do, a glitchy blank plot appears.

My issue with react-plotly is that I can an error when I try to require the source code. For some reason React.createClass crashes inside the react-plotly code...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createClass' of undefined
```

Here is the relevant code, it is pretty simple and it is good enough to get a plot going with my data with react-plotly, I just cannot update the plots data...

```
var React = require ('react');

var MyStore = require ('./stores/MyStore');

var MyForm = require ('./components/MyForm.jsx');

const Plotly = require('react-plotlyjs');

var trace1 = {
r: [6.80498578527, 3.38959601061, 5.38147211075, 8.05954021942, 5.31822922787, 2.98509993563, 1.96658700238, 6.76926540821, 4.07340189872, 6.50437182527, 7.556369819, 4.04745609407, 7.38666249607, 5.41362473698, 7.47071653116, 7.98211021694, 4.73781408009, 4.20645304293, 5.47860480459, 4.8245202807, 5.5996006099, 6.86679521708, 3.08567136626, 7.77181094323, 3.6877944351, 5.36035668519, 5.1404467393, 6.04544568093, 6.83392094019, 3.62076946254, 3.9894305834, 5.3118244995, 4.60821348028, 6.64058471615, 3.05518885448, 7.49256416375, 5.48507817779, 3.89779499662, 5.97624511403, 5.44706156091, 5.37703411681, 4.69080578773, 4.71164049118, 3.62991932939, 5.95766807637, 5.35712128439, 3.84923528282, 6.25050713632, 7.12224335715, 3.39940423384, 3.51055667227, 4.10099760366, 4.0963821002, 6.23358307481, 3.93948852677, 3.9254450774, 6.11813250146, 3.94045034629, 7.58301557326, 3.51320214534],
t: [-30.3529443619, -25.6114598545, -12.4252274527, 13.9613805187, -4.95093284067, -25.6922741909, 12.4687641616, -4.91376410703, -10.9673802876, 30.8141940549, 2.47495943114, 17.9755437524, 0.771130593362, 6.13748848563, -14.451963574, 28.1845341129, 12.538680066, -8.98323033713, 5.23128516476, -64.4890025358, 11.3574866818, 3.45407479151, 13.9243466131, -25.3640020468, -16.818006386, -10.2600510306, -13.2121341256, 2.5793388653, 8.71757496585, -10.6754987192, -2.92636601252, 25.1958807548, 40.5903293216, -9.12143363019, -24.2973623813, -3.17694450569, 10.8504984192, -31.3320597474, 4.84956746221, 15.0482769541, 3.29510469926, -6.19709187313, -8.77857413578, 29.5491741194, -5.13744879288, 23.0268604879, -6.63481657837, 2.75501499186, 21.7332501137, -24.8169949601, -7.83054706253, 28.3257962102, 12.3009774678, -21.56315724, -19.3355162838, 26.1464431708, -1.70607120268, 16.071723695, 2.05326630285, -5.09791161233],
mode: 'markers',
name: 'Trial 1',
marker: {
color: 'rgb(27,158,119)',
size: 110,
line: {color: 'white'},
opacity: 0.7
},
type: 'scatter'
};

//<NOTE: I deleted the other "trace 2-6" variables from the code example, it is too verbose and is not the problem>

var layout = {
title: 'Hobbs-Pearson Trials',
font: {size: 15},
plot_bgcolor: 'rgb(223, 223, 223)',
angularaxis: {tickcolor: 'rgb(253,253,253)'}
};

var data2 = [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4, trace5, trace6];
var data3 = [trace1];

var App = React.createClass ({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      name : MyStore.getName (),
      data2: data2
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    MyStore.addChangeListener (this._onChange);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    MyStore.removeChangeListener (this._onChange);
  },
  _onChange: function () {
    this.setState ({
      name: MyStore.getName (),
      data2: data3,
      layout: layout
    },
    function()
    {
      this.forceUpdate(function()
        {console.log("force update called")}
      )

    });
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2> Hello, {this.state.name}! </h2>
        <MyForm />
        <Plotly id="polarScatterPlot" data={this.state.data2} layout={layout}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

/*
 *  Render your React UI on the page.
 */
React.render (
  <App />,
  document.body
);
```

Comment: Does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/13148/

Comment: Does that code use a plotly react wrapper? The external resources don't list one. Did you get plotly to work in react without a wrapper?

Comment: I blatantly stole the react-plotly implementation from their github.

Comment: okay I will try it out and let you know

Comment: I get the same "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createClass' of undefined" at the line where I "require" it... I feel like I am in the twighlight zone. I have not had this issue with any other npm library. Any ideas on what I could try to get around this issue?

Comment: so my brain turned off a moment ago, I took away my require... and now it worked... but I still need to see if I can update the data :/

Comment: I see the timeout thing you added and it worked! Please make an answer out of your awesome comments and I will accept it :)

Comment: There is no straight answer here. Your problem probably lies in how you change the data in your store. The way I solved it was by using `setTimeout`, which is not the way you want to go about it, you probably want to fire an action that updates the data.

Comment: The fact that you used setTimeout is not an obstacle for me. I was stuck because I am naive at React and I could not understand why the react-plotly code and react-plotlyjs code was not working for me. Now I have plotly.js finally working in react whew!

Comment: @smuggledPancakes if you would be inclined to tell us how, at least this react user would be glad.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are referencing `react-plotly.js` and not `react-plotly` (also the dependency needs to include the `.js`)

Comment: also make sure that when you install you run exactly `npm install react-plotly.js plotly.js` and do not remove the `.js`. I removed the `.js` on first attempt and got the error above. Follow guide here: https://plotly.com/javascript/react/